# GitHub Actions with encrypted SECRET_KEY as environmental variable do not work

Tags: python, django, workflow, github-actions

I don't have much experience in coding. I am currently writing a small Django application. Following all the rules, I do not want to place the SECRET_KEY in the repository, so I created the SECRET_KEY environment variable in the .bashrс file. And in the settings.py file I wrote: `SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get ('SECRET_KEY')`
When I execute
`pylint --load-plugins pylint_django my_application` in the terminal on my computer everything works. I get a response

> Your code has been rated at 9.88 / 10

Also I have workflow pylint.yaml to accomplish pylint-django tests on push trigger, when I send my files to my GitHub repo:

```
name: Pylint

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up Python 3.8
      uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: 3.8
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install -r requirements.txt
    - name: Analysing the code with pylint 
      run: |
        pylint --load-plugins pylint_django rm
```

When I am pushing my files to GitHub, I reseive this:

```
Run pylint --load-plugins pylint_django rm
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.12/x64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pylint_django/checkers/foreign_key_strings.py", line 90, in open
    django.setup()
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.12/x64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.12/x64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 82, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.12/x64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 63, in _setup
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting LOGGING_CONFIG, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.12/x64/bin/pylint", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(run_pylint())
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.12/x64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pylint/__init__.py", line 24, in run_pylint
    PylintRun(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.12/x64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pylint/lint/run.py", line 374, in __init__
    linter.check(args)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.12/x64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pylint/lint/pylinter.py", line 970, in check
    self._check_files(
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.12/x64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pylint/lint/pylinter.py", line 1005, in _check_files
    with self._astroid_module_checker() as check_astroid_module:
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.12/x64/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 113, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.12/x64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pylint/lint/pylinter.py", line 1127, in _astroid_module_checker
    checker.open()
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.12/x64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pylint_django/checkers/foreign_key_strings.py", line 114, in open
    django.setup()
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.12/x64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.12/x64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 122, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.12/x64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/apps.py", line 27, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.12/x64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 24, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.12/x64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 47, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.12/x64/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.12/x64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/admin.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import (
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.12/x64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py", line 11, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.tokens import default_token_generator
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.12/x64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/tokens.py", line 117, in <module>
    default_token_generator = PasswordResetTokenGenerator()
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.12/x64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/tokens.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.secret = self.secret or settings.SECRET_KEY
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.12/x64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 90, in __getattr__
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

It`s look like GitHub-hosted runner dont see the value of my SECRET_KEY, encripted in .bashrc file
on my local machine.
I tried to change my file Like this:

```
name: Pylint

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up Python 3.8
      uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: 3.8
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install -r requirements.txt
    - name: Analysing the code with pylint 
      run: |
        export SECRET_KEY=${{ secrets.SECRET_KEY }}
        export DB_USER=${{ secrets.DB_USER }}
        export DB_PASSWORD=${{ secrets.DB_PASSWORD }}
        export DB_NAME=${{ secrets.DB_NAME }}
        pylint --load-plugins pylint_django rm
```

Then i got this error:

```
Run export  SECRET_KEY=***
/home/runner/work/_temp/87974674-0535-4fca-ab32-30cf1a19f030.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `4h%fzr+bqqsmg8ftp-a$4%b'
Error: Process completed with exit code 2.
```

I changed my pylint.yaml file to this one:

```
name: Pylint

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up Python 3.8
      uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: 3.8
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install -r requirements.txt
    - name: Analysing the code with pylint # SECRET_KEY is generated with DJANGO SECRET KEY GENERATOR
      run: |
        export SECRET_KEY=0-42!#@*6jqo)lv^+@-+&(-@kjke@xzk%)1!w)vz-1uwk71p)=
        export DB_USER=${{ secrets.DB_USER }}
        export DB_PASSWORD=${{ secrets.DB_PASSWORD }}
        export DB_NAME=${{ secrets.DB_NAME }}
        pylint --load-plugins pylint_django rm
```

and got this error:

```
Run export SECRET_KEY=0-42!#@*6jqo)lv^+@-+&(-@kjke@xzk%)1!w)vz-1uwk71p)=
/home/runner/work/_temp/fdbfd3cd-9022-4cd6-833c-0aef801ddddb.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
Error: Process completed with exit code 2.
```

How can I tell my pylint workflow what SECRET_KEY to use in pylint.yaml file to pass tests?

Please, help.I've already spent a lot of time thinking and searching on the Internet and GitHub documentation, but I haven't found anything for myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was very close to the solution. Due to the fact that the `SECRET_KEY` contains parentheses, you need to enclose the `SECRET_KEY` in double quotes.

```
 - name: Analysing the code with pylint # SECRET_KEY is generated with DJANGO SECRET KEY GENERATOR
      run: |
        export SECRET_KEY="0-42!#@*6jqo)lv^+@-+&(-@kjke@xzk%)1!w)vz-1uwk71p)="
        export DB_USER=${{ secrets.DB_USER }}
        export DB_PASSWORD=${{ secrets.DB_PASSWORD }}
        export DB_NAME=${{ secrets.DB_NAME }}
        pylint --load-plugins pylint_django rm
```

Comment: Another option would have been to add the KEY as repo secret, then add the `env` field to step running the script with the value `SECRET_KEY=${{secrets.SECRET_REPO_NAME}}`

Comment: In my situation, this varisnt gave the following error: ```Run export SECRET_KEY=***
/home/runner/work/_temp/8e67d0f8-99e9-4b64-a15f-c376aa71b497.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `4h%fzr+bqqsmg8ftp-a$4%b'
Error: Process completed with exit code 2.``` As if GITHUB doesn't reveal the whole ```SECRET_KEY``` sequence in the workflow.

Comment: My bad then. I believe it was possible to use this in the past, but as it might lead to a secret vulnerability (if you print it after retrieving the calue as an env variable in your script), they might have treated the problem that way (which is great, but make what you want to achieve harder).